# mysqli multiple queries - set variable produces boolean error/how to skip this?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, multi-query

Got the following simple query which works fine through phpmyadmin but when I add it to my php website no results are returned and no error/warning messages either. If I remove "SET @N=-1;" then it works fine.

```
<?php 
$db_connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, true);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $db_connect);

$test_query = mysql_query("SET @N=-1;SELECT `id`, (@N:=@N+1) AS `mycount` FROM `mydb`;");

for ($i = 0; $i <= mysql_num_rows($test_query)-1; $i++) {
   echo mysql_result($db_directorymap, $i, 0) . " " . mysql_result($db_directorymap, $i, 1) . "<br />";
}
?>
```

UPDATE: I just moved to mysqli but of course I'm still having a problem with the mysql statement and mysqli_multi_query. It seems when it runs the first part of the query the results returned are empty thus a boolean error is given. I'm guessing I have to skip the first set of results but I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `mysql_query` function will only accept one query, but you've given it two, separated by a semicolon. Try either:

1. Running each query separately (don't know if this will work):

   ```
    mysql_query( "SET @N=-1" );
    mysql_query( "SELECT `id`, (@N:=@N+1) AS `mycount` FROM `mydb`" );
   ```
2. Using [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) with the [multi_query](https://www.php.net/mysqli.multi-query) function (or a [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) equivalent if there is one).

To answer your updated question: check the PHP manual page for multi_query. I think you'll want to use `mysqli::next_result`. Something like this, using procedural style:

```
mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);
mysqli_next_result($link);

if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Nuh, still can't figure this one out. It's doing my head in! I can't figure out how to go to the next result set without incuring error "Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given". I can't use errno() because I get boolean response and I can't get past the boolean response without calling the query in the first place!? There's got to be a way around this...

Comment: You probably don't need to free the first result (it's freed at the end of the script anyway). But from the error you may be passing the wrong variable into the function - you need to pass the $result variable from `$result = mysqli_store_result($link)`. I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple queries via mysql_query aren't supported, so I'd guess that it's only executing the SET command, and not the subsequent SELECT command.