# SET @var := SELECT * FROM table_name: is it possible

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, set

I'm trying to write my MySQL query, but I'm stuck on this - I have multiple queries from my php to the SQL database:

```
SET @var := SELECT MAX(first_column)
    FROM table;

SELECT @var, 
    table.second_column
FROM table;
```

But it returns SQL error. When I use it in phpmyadmin, it works fine. I've googled and I saw people use "SET @var = MySQL query" only in stored procedures. Is it possible to use it the way I want?

Comment: Who's giving you error? Maybe PHP can't run two queries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli multiple queries - set variable produces boolean error/how to skip this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227022/mysqli-multiple-queries-set-variable-produces-boolean-error-how-to-skip-this)

Comment: Would be nice to know what the text of the SQL error is....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running multiple queries (i.e., you have a `;` in your query), you either need to run it as two separate queries, or use a command like [**`mysqli_multi_query`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).  The [**`mysql_query`**](http://php.net/mysql_query) command can only run a single query at a time.

```
mysql_query('SET @VAR := SELECT MAX(first_column) FROM TABLE');
mysql_query('SELECT @var, table.second_column FROM table');
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227022/mysqli-multiple-queries-set-variable-produces-boolean-error-how-to-skip-this).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that there could be only one query. I've tried to make multiple queries because I think it would be a slightly faster than separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(first_column) INTO @var FROM table; 
SELECT @var,table.second_column FROM table;
```